# How can I assign a css framework class to a bare HTML element?

Tags: css, less, jekyll, semantic-ui

I'm using [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com) for my [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com) blog.

I want to assign the css classes `.ui .celled .table` to each table used in a blog post. With Jekyll, I'm not able to set styles for generated elements globally. I theoretically could do that in every table in every blog post separately like this:

```
{:class="ui celled table"}
| Change       | Description |
| :----------- | :---------- |
| A            | Lorem ipsum |
```

But that seems too verbose and is easy to forget.

I tried inheriting the style with LESS in `site.overrides` for each `<table>` element, but that didn't work:

```
table {
    &:extend(.ui.celled.table);
}
```

How can I best set the Semantic UI table style for all tables globally?

Comment: What about jquery, is that an option for you?

Comment: The site works completely without Javascript right now. But if there's no other way, I guess Javascript would be acceptable.

Comment: Like this: $().ready(function(){ $("table").addClass("ui celled table"); }

Should set all tables with the classes.